# How to send Email Notification in HapiJS..?

Tags: notifications, hapi.js, email-notifications, hapi

I am working on a project written with HapiJS. the project is related to the interview process So,
I have to make **email notification service** in HapiJs whenever the interview will schedule.

when the interview will schedule the interviewer and the candidate will get an email notification.
How I can make this in HapiJs in the best way?

Please someone could help me in this scenario, how I have to proceed and make.
I am new to HapiJs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't handle this with Hapi. Hapi is just an API framework. What you are looking for is job scheduling or cron jobs on Nodejs. This is how you should research.

Comment: Thanks for the info @vencra, so I have to make this via Nodejs and search for the same..?? If possible, can you please provide me with some examples?